# Expanding GROUPing of Complex SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a query that grabs a count of keyword occurrences across 4 distinct time series (in this case, 4 different weeks).

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN request_unixtime > 1453907061 AND request_unixtime < 1454511861 THEN 'cnt3' 
        WHEN request_unixtime > 1454511861 AND request_unixtime < 1455116661 THEN 'cnt2' 
        WHEN request_unixtime > 1455116661 AND request_unixtime < 1455721461 THEN 'cnt1' 
        WHEN request_unixtime > 1455721461 AND request_unixtime < 1456412661 THEN 'cnt' 
    END, 
    count(*) FROM keywords 
WHERE 
    keyword = 'football' 
    AND request_unixtime > 1453907061 AND request_unixtime < 1456412661 

GROUP BY CASE 
    WHEN request_unixtime > 1453907061 AND request_unixtime < 1454511861 THEN 'cnt3' 
    WHEN request_unixtime > 1454511861 AND request_unixtime < 1455116661 THEN 'cnt2' 
    WHEN request_unixtime > 1455116661 AND request_unixtime < 1455721461 THEN 'cnt2' 
    WHEN request_unixtime > 1455721461 AND request_unixtime < 1456412661 THEN 'cnt' 

END;
```

Whose results look something like this...

```
=============
| cnt  | 35 |
| cnt2 | 30 |
| cnt3 | 27 |
| cnt4 | 41 |
```

However, I would like to be able to perform this for multiple keywords simultaneously. Instead of having

```
WHERE keyword='football'
```

I'd like to have

```
WHERE keyword IN ('football','soccer','tennis)
```

But I don't know how to reformulate the CASE and GROUP BY to end up with a result that breaks the counts out by keyword. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as adding the keyword to the `SELECT` list and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    K.keyword,
    CASE
        WHEN K.request_unixtime > 1453907061 AND K.request_unixtime < 1454511861 THEN 'cnt3' 
        WHEN K.request_unixtime > 1454511861 AND K.request_unixtime < 1455116661 THEN 'cnt2' 
        WHEN K.request_unixtime > 1455116661 AND K.request_unixtime < 1455721461 THEN 'cnt1' 
        WHEN K.request_unixtime > 1455721461 AND K.request_unixtime < 1456412661 THEN 'cnt' 
    END AS time_series,
    count(*) AS cnt
FROM
    Keywords K
WHERE
    K.request_unixtime > 1453907061 AND
    K.request_unixtime < 1456412661 AND
    K.keyword IN ('football', 'tennis', 'soccer')
GROUP BY
    K.keyword,
    CASE
        WHEN K.request_unixtime > 1453907061 AND K.request_unixtime < 1454511861 THEN 'cnt3' 
        WHEN K.request_unixtime > 1454511861 AND K.request_unixtime < 1455116661 THEN 'cnt2' 
        WHEN K.request_unixtime > 1455116661 AND K.request_unixtime < 1455721461 THEN 'cnt1' 
        WHEN K.request_unixtime > 1455721461 AND K.request_unixtime < 1456412661 THEN 'cnt' 
    END;
```

If you'll be looking at the data directly (rather than calling this code from a front end/report) then you'll probably want to add an `ORDER BY` as well.

Comment: You can't have `AS` in the `GROUP BY` clause. You can just use `GROUP BY K.keyword, time_series`.

Comment: Cut & Paste error. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll remove it now.